# PDF view changes from 100% to 71% after clicking on link to page

Tags: links, texworks

Starting PDF view is as follows:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.0}}

\hypersetup{pdfremotestartview={XYZ null null 1.0}}

\hypersetup{pdfview={XYZ null null 1.0}}
```

I am linking some external pages using following line:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.95,link=true,linkname=name_of_link,pagecommand=
{\refstepcounter{includepdfpage}\label{testing.\theincludepdfpage}}]{filename.pdf}
```

and creating link to that page using this line:

```
\hyperlink{testing_17.1}{some_text_to_display}
```

the linking is properly reflecting in output pdf file i.e, when I click on text its taking me to the page with `link-name = testing_17.1` (1st page of `testing_17`) but, PDF view changes from 100% to 71%.

Any solution for keeping view as set i.e, 100% here?

Comment: Make a complete example. You can use one of the pdf from the mwe package for the includepdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default pdfpages uses /Fit for the destinations it creates. You can change this with the `linkfit` option. Beside the documented values Fit, FitH etc it also knows the value `XZY <number>` (yes XZY, not XYZ). With `<number>` = 1000 you get a zoom of 1.

An other possibility is to redefine the pdfpages command to use the hyperref pdfview option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{includepdfpage}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}

\hypersetup{pdfremotestartview={XYZ null null 1}}

\hypersetup{pdfview={XYZ null null 1}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pdfcompresslevel0

\makeatletter
% Alternative: patch pdfpages:
%\def\AM@dest@special{\AM@destination name {\AM@linkname.\AM@page} \@pdfview}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\lipsum

\hyperlink{xxx.1}{some text to display}

\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.95,link,
            linkname=xxx,linkfit=XZY 1000]{example-image-a4.pdf}
\end{document}
```

A last option is not to use the links created by pdfpages but as you are setting \labels anyway to reference to these labels:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{includepdfpage}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1}}

\hypersetup{pdfremotestartview={XYZ null null 1}}

\hypersetup{pdfview={XYZ null null 1}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\hyperref[xxx.1]{some text to display}

\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.95,
pagecommand={\refstepcounter{includepdfpage}\label{xxx.\number\value{includepdfpage}}}]{example-image-a4.pdf}
\lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Comment: setting linkfit=XZY 1000 worked for me..Thank you very much. :)